# Sql Query for Selecting between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me with selecting programs between two dates.

The requirement is that a Start date and end date will be in two columns.Depending on the range records between them should be selected.

Lets take a real example..

[image: Example output]

The date is divided into two: `StartDate` and `EndDate`.

If I want to select the matches which are in between July 10 & July 14, then I can write a query like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tblMatch 
WHERE (StartDate BETWEEN '7/9/14' AND '7/13/14' ) 
and (EndDate BETWEEN '7/9/14' AND '7/13/14')
```

But If there is mistake in the range specified, I need to select the correct match based on StartDate or End Date.

If a user searches with :

```
                 StartDate:7/10/14    -- 10 July 2014
                 EndDate: 7/15/14     -- 15 July 2014
                       or
                 StartDate:7/8/14     -- 8 July 2014
                 EndDate: 7/14/14     -- 14 July 2014
```

Then the match between the range which is first match in my case should be selected!!

**UPDATE** My StartDate and EndDate are Sql Date data types only...So please do think about it, before saying is the problem with conversion...

Based on the range the events between them should be selected.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer date format details from: [Date format URL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

```sql
-- 101 is forma "mm/dd/yy":

select * from tblMatch 
where (CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),StartDate,101) between '07/09/14' and '07/13/14' ) 
and (CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),EndDate,101) between '07/09/14' and '07/13/14')
```

Comment: My problem is not with the query i have tried..i want the correct for my requirement which u would understand if u read question again

Comment: It's correct not problem in logic. Problem in range of date format only. Please check and replay.

Comment: My StartDate and EndDate columns are sql date types only...There is no need for conversion...

Comment: Ok, then not problem in query, to continue your query there is not any logic problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDate1 DATETIME = 7/10/14;
DECLARE @EndDate1 DATETIME = 7/15/14;

DECLARE @StartDate2 DATETIME = 7/8/14;
DECLARE @EndDate2 DATETIME = 7/14/14;

SELECT * FROM tblMatch
WHERE (StartDate > @StartDate1 AND EndDate < @EndDate1) OR (StartDate > @StartDate2 AND EndDate < @EndDate2);
```

Comment: Thanx for ur but answer, actually i am not using 4 parameters to search ..Either StartDAte1, EndDate1 or StartDate2,EndDate2...

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tblMatch 
where (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),StartDate,110) between '12/01/14' and '12/31/14' ) 
and (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),EndDate,110) between '12/01/14' and '12/31/14')
```

Here date format is `"MM/dd/yyyy"`.